# Multiplication of sparse matrices in python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have some code that I have written in R, which works for matrices. I have been asked to translate this into python to implement using sparse matrices.

I have two csr_matrices `mat1` and `mat2`. At the moment I am matrix multiplying them together using

```
product = mat1 @ mat2
```

It's important that this algorithm be efficient, is this the best way to multiply sparse matrices? I can't find any documentation online for matrix multiplication of sparse matrices, only pointwise multiplication. I don't want to use this function if it is converting into normal matrices, multiplying and then converting back if there is a more computationally efficient way.

Comment: @ is sparse's best math operation.  Actually `mat1*mat2` does the same thing since these are modeled on `np.matrix`. `mat1.dot(mat2)` also.

Comment: Scipy sparse multiplication is single threaded. If speed is a thing you need that could be an issue.